# How to Restore Custom Field Data on Validation Error

Tags: php, plugins, wordpress

Thanks for your time.

I need to know how to re-fill fields from an external plugin I won't be modifying directly.  When a user fills one but not the other and both are required, it should stay filled so that it doesn't have to be retyped.

Example in raw php: http://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_form_validation_complete

Comment: It's not clear from your question, but if you're trying to validate inputs when saving a post I would suggest looking at [this other question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5102/add-validation-and-error-handling-when-saving-custom-fields) that attempts to address the matter.  You should be able to accomplish what you're after with the `save_post` action, where the job of actually saving information to the database is being performed.

Comment: Thank you, but the problem is not the hook (we use wp_insert_post and pre_post_update for different goals at the moment).  The problem is that the normal way of assigning data to $_POST does not work from these custom fields.  WordPress appears to break the ability to grab data from $_POST after reload from the previous page.  I need a workaround to that.

Comment: Since you state that you can't edit the plugin itself, another option would be to provide client-side code to check for the Publish/Update button click and prevent form submission if you don't like the inputs.  http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/15627/60176 documents how you might capture the attempt to save the post and inject your own validation logic at that point, even going so far as to provide you with server-side validation ability (using Ajax actions) should that prove helpful.

Comment: Is there no way to reference $_POST then?  WordPress breaks this irrevocably?